# jury-rigging an automotive catalytic converter for use in the Ostwald Process?

Tags: organic-chemistry, catalysis

Would it be feasible to jury-rig an automotive catalytic converter for use in the Ostwald Process for the production of Nitric Acid? Given reasonable safety precautions, would it be safe enough to be practical for a home lab?

A Catalytic converter is a device used in cars to reduce Nitric oxide into nitrogen and Oxygen, as well as oxidizing Carbon monoxide and unburnt hydrocarbons into Co2 and H20.

What I'm proposing is feeding ammonia and oxygen into it at an appropriate temperature and pressure to produce the Nitric Oxide necessary to create Further oxidize into Nitrogen Dioxide, which is reacted with water to produce Nitric acid and Nitric Oxide.

4 NH<sub>3 (g)</sub> + 5 O<sub>2 (g)</sub> → 4 NO <sub>(g)</sub> + 6 H<sub>2</sub>O <sub>(g)</sub> (ΔH = −905.2 kJ)
2 NO <sub>(g)</sub> + O<sub>2 (g)</sub> → 2 NO<sub>2 (g)</sub> (ΔH = −114 kJ/mol)
3 NO<sub>2 (g)</sub> + H<sub>2</sub>O <sub>(l)</sub> → 2 HNO<sub>3 (aq)</sub> + NO <sub>(g)</sub> (ΔH = −117 kJ/mol)

So my Question is whether a Catalytic Converter salvaged from an automobile is a suitable substitute for a column packed with Platinum gauze.

Comment: The Ostwald process requires high pressures and produces gaseous nitric acid. This is industrial chemistry, not home chemistry.

Comment: Why are you trying to produce nitric acid anyway? Just go and buy some.